# how to render a sitecore partial without pulling it in as a datasource?

Tags: sitecore, partial-views

You can create a versioned image in Sitecore by referencing its item url like so:

```
    <img src="~/media/CEB3BE892F3E47E9BCEC3F357F974606.ashx">
```

Is there a similar way to reuse a portion of html? Say a header or footer or dropdown menu, for example.

I'm familiar with how to do this in Rails, but don't have the user privileges I'd need in Sitecore to be able to do this in anything other than html/css/js. I can't modify the templates or go into the C# code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking here. The Html in your question, is the result of a rendered image field. The image could be versioned, or not. It doesn't have anything to do with the html.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In Rails, you can render a partial in your erb files like so:  `<%= render partial: "header" %>`. That partial would show the header, which has been coded elsewhere. Is there a similar way of accomplishing this in Sitecore?

Comment: Is this an MVC or WebForms site?

Answer (score -2):

Depending on whether you're using Web Forms or MVC you'll want to know about either Asp.Net MVC Partial Views, or Asp.Net User Controls to create a sublayout/rendering.

However since you don't have access to the code, I don't think there's really anything you can do.